# mysql_real_escape_string in PHP CLI

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a script that I want to cron scheduled. Its all fine and dandy when I tested in the browser, working as it should but when run from php cli (php cron.php), mysql_real_escape_string loses the value given.

Any idea why?

UPDATED with code and a connection made before mysql_real_escape_string (but still not working)

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", 'xxx', 'xxx');  
foreach ($prosArr[$i] as $val => $key) {
    $fieldsStr  .= "`".trim($val). '` , ';
    $fieldVal   .= '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($key). '" , ';
}
```

Here is output print_r of $prosArr[$i] obtained straight from the same CLI script

```
Array
(
    [ProductCode] => 10077
    [BranchCode] => 100
    [RetailPrice] => 499.0000
    [PromotionPrice] => 0.0000
    [FullPrice] => 499.0000
)
```

Comment: Please show some code. Do you have a mySQL connection active?

Comment: Hard to determine the reasons without any clue

Comment: I wish I have more clue. It works for sure in browser. The value returns as it should. It just doesn't when I start it in CLI.

Comment: @exentric: does the PHP version is the same in cli and in the webserver?

Comment: you mess with PDO and mysql_* function ... and probably is a bad idea

Comment: @exentric: yep like ajreal said you should stick only with one API, you should use the escapement from PDO

Comment: @ajreal - can't say I'm fond of it. I picked this up from my colleague. Most of the stuff truly bewildered me myself. Is that the problem? mysql_real_escape_string might have issues with PDO?

Comment: @exentric both are two doing two different things, you need either using PDO alone or mysql_* alone, you can't mix together.

Comment: @RageZ - The thing is, the original connection was using Magento's connection resource. But after many crashes later on my windows machine, I decided to use PDO which doesn't crash. I figured it wouldn't be a problem since the only Magento part is executing the SQL. But since its useless if I can't run through CLI, I guess I'll be spending some quality time changing the codes to use PDO fully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with PDO. They are different libraries and have are not meant to be used with each other.

Use [`PDO::Quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or parametrized queries instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, how is a script run different in a browser and in CLI? It was working in a browser meaning I do have a connection and of course, the data even when returned with no value, was inserted into the DB without issue and I know there is nothing in between that establishes a connection. But alas, I'll just make another connection just before it.

Comment: @exentric there is no fundamental difference - impossible to tell what might be wrong without seeing some code

Comment: yeah that's what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://de3.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), you should connect to MySQL first.

On the documentation in the note section

> A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string()
>   otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is
>   returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection
>   is used.

---

EDIT: You should use the [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and not mix mysql and PDO API